# manage uitableview with more than 1000 rows with images iphone

Tags: iphone, image-processing, memory-leaks, uitableview

I have a table view with more than 1000 rows. and every cell have a image of large size approx 2-3 mb. I receive the low memory warning. so can any one suggest how i manage this table view. Loading images from web server and saving locally. so please suggest which approach should i follow.

code of cell for row at index path:

```
savedFile =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", appDeligate.ThumbNailPath, fileName];


            if ([clsGlobal isFileExist:savedFile]) {
                objCellRecent.imgView.image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedFile];

            }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can write each image downloaded to disk to save from memory warning. Or release cached images when you receive the memory warning.

Comment: can you provide some code of your cell for row at indexpath method

Comment: Hi AAAAAAAA I have update my post and added code for cell for row at index path. thx

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load a 1000 images of 2-3 mb each on to the device. What you can do is maintain a stack of say 50 rows at a time and overwrite images within this stack. 
This stack shall be of the rows which are currently present on the screen and rows around them say you are showing 10 rows at a time then you maintain those ten and 40 around those ten say for instance 20 up and 20 down.
Let me know if that works out well cause i have not tried this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps as I see it.

1. Make thumbnails
   There is no need (even if it should be possible, which it's not) to have 2-3mb sized images displayed in a table with 1000rows on a small screen like the iphone. Instead, once pressed or entered detail view, then the 2-3mb image could be retrieved.
2. Only retrieve a limited number of thumbnails at a time
   Load only a fraction of the 1000 thumbnails from start, possibly around 40-50 (that is the ones that are visible on screen, and a few outside and closest to the screen). When scrolling,  start loading more thumbnails.